# SQL Server trigger - works on UPDATE but not on INSERT

Tags: sql-server

The following trigger (which updates a column in the same table as the insert or update) works perfectly for UPDATEs, but doesn't seem to fire for INSERTs. Is it possible to run an update on?

What am I missing?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnEvaluationCreateOrEdit] 
ON [dbo].[tblEvaluationFormResultsSummary] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- get the last id value of the record inserted or updated
    DECLARE @id  BIGINT;

    SELECT @id = EvaluationFormResultSummaryID
    FROM INSERTED;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    UPDATE A
    SET A.Outcome =  CASE 
                        WHEN B.[# of fail alls] > 0 THEN 'Poor' 
                        WHEN B.[# of Fail Amber] / [# of Live Questions] >= 0.3 THEN 'Poor'
                        WHEN B.[# of Fail Amber] > 0 THEN 'Development Needed'
                        WHEN B.[# of Fail Green] / [# of Live Questions] >= 0.4 THEN 'Development Needed'
                        WHEN B.[# of Fail Green] > 0 THEN 'Right First Time - Coaching Required'
                        ELSE 'Right First Time'
                     END
    FROM
        dbo.tblEvaluationFormResultsSummary AS A
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT        
             SUM(CASE WHEN FormQuestionRatingOptionFailAll = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [# of fail alls],
             SUM(CASE WHEN FormQuestionRatingOptionIsNA = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [# of N/A],
             SUM(CASE WHEN FormQuestionRatingOptionLabel = 'Fail / Amber' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [# of Fail Amber],
             COUNT(EFRS.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID) as [No of Questions],
             COUNT(EFRS.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID) - SUM(CASE WHEN FormQuestionRatingOptionIsNA = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [# of Live Questions],
             SUM(CASE WHEN FormQuestionRatingOptionLabel = 'Fail / Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [# of Fail Green],
             EFRS.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID
         FROM  
             dbo.tblEvaluationFormResultsDetails AS EFRS 
         INNER JOIN 
             dbo.tblEvaluationFormQuestionRatingOptions AS RO ON EFRS.QuestionRatingOptionID = RO.FormQuestionRatingOptionID
         WHERE        
             (EFRS.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID = @id)
         GROUP BY 
             EFRS.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID) B ON a.EvaluationFormResultSummaryID = B.EvaluationFormResultsSummaryID
    WHERE 
        A.EvaluationFormResultSummaryID = @id
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a no-no: "SELECT @id = EvaluationFormResultSummaryID
  FROM INSERTED;" ... the "inserted" collection can and will contain multiple rows (ESPECIALLY in an update case), so you're just getting the ID of basically the last row.  NEVER DO THIS STUFF IN A TRIGGER.  All operations must assume set operations, and multiple rows in inserted and/or deleted.

Comment: Other than what pmbAustin pointed out above, I see nothing in your trigger code that would cause it to work for UPDATE but not INSERT.  I conclude that you are misinterpreting what you are seeing.   Probably because of the above referenced issue.   Voting to close as un-reproducible / non-issue.